# Multiple questions for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How would I do the following in Visual Basic Express?

a) Press "delete", "home", and "shift" on the keyboard with the program. // Still need to figure out how to do this.
b) Detect when "z" and "x" are pressed. // I'm using buttons instead of this part now.

Thanks so much! :)

- Windows Form Application

Comment: Is this WEB Forms, WIN Forms, MVC, ETC???

Comment: Windows Form Application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is "ONE" way.. it detects the <kbd>Enter</kbd> press in .NET Win Forms.  The 13 represents "Enter".

```
   Public Function KeyAscii(ByVal UserKeyArgument As KeyPressEventArgs) As Short
        KeyAscii = Asc(UserKeyArgument.KeyChar)
    End Function

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If KeyAscii(e) = 13 Then
            MsgBox("you press ENTER key")
        End If
    End Sub
```

More key types can be found by using something like this to detect your key presses.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Debug.Print "KeyAscii: " & KeyAscii
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Form1.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the SendKey function would meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

a) To send keyboard commands, you can use this [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.
b) To capture keystrokes check out this [support article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320583)